# Lambda Statements in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csquery

Is it possible to do something like the following in Linq?

```
List<Group> groupsCollection = new List<Group>();
groups.Select( g => {
    String id = g.Attributes["id"].Value;
    String title = g.Attributes["title"].Value;
    groupsCollection.Add( new Group(id, title) );
} );
```

This is just an example. I know a Foreach loop would be sufficient but I was querying whether it would be possible or not.

I tried it, and it's saying:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type System.Collections.IEnumerable<CsQuery.IDomObject> because it's not a delegate type
```

Edit: Group is my custom class. Groups are a collection of CsQuery Dom Objects. You can think of them as a collection of html anchor elements. They are IEnumerable.

Comment: or the bigger question is, what is the variable "groups"?

Comment: A custom AddRange overload would be much cleaner.

Comment: You can always write your methods with iterator block to wrap something as an `IEnumerable` of what can be done with foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
groupsCollection = groups.Select(g =>
    new Group(g.Attributes["id"].Value,
              g.Attributes["title"].Value)).ToList();
```

**Explanation:**

`Select()` projects each element of a sequence into a new form. (From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx))

It's basically a transformation function that takes one IEnumerable and transforms it, in whatever way you like, to another IEnumerable, which seems to be exactly what you want here.

Comment: This assumes the variable "groups" is an IEnumerable

Comment: If `groups` wasn't `IEnumerable` the error in the OP's code would be different.

Comment: and you could just do "=> expression" instead of "=> {statement;}", if you want.

Comment: Thanks for having my back, Eren. :)

Comment: @JoeCool no problem :) sorry but your latest update is not valid -- there is no `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. `ForEach`is a method on `List<T>`, and it pre-dates linq. I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that. Since he doesn't say if `groups` is an actual `List` or not, I'll take that out of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Select()` takes a lambda expression that *returns a value*; it shouldn't have any sife effects.

You want

```
var groupsCollection = groups.Select(g => {
    return ...;
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) to initialize it with the query:

```
var query = groups.Select( g => {
    String id = g.Attributes["id"].Value;
    String title = g.Attributes["title"].Value;
    return new Group(id, title);
});
List<Group> groupsCollection = new List<Group>(query);
```

Do not modify colections in a linq-query, instead select data that can be used to modify collections.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you know using `ForEach` would be relevant. However you are **just curious** if you can do it another way. As others pointed out, you can use `Select` but the code in the `{...}` should return some value. However, you can do it this way which is better if you want to `stop` or `break` the loop depending on some condition using `TakeWhile`:

```
groups.TakeWhile( g => {
       String id = g.Attributes["id"].Value;
       String title = g.Attributes["title"].Value;
       groupsCollection.Add( new Group(id, title) );
       return true;//If you want to break the loop, just return false accordingly.
    });
```